# Using TinyXML ( linking libraries ? in c++ )

Tags: c++, tinyxml

+Hi...
i am a newbie ... and i don't know how to include external libraries in c++.
This is sooo hard.

I want to use TinyXML.
so i made this :

example2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tinyxml.h"


void write_app_settings_doc( )  
{  
    TiXmlDocument doc;  
    TiXmlElement* msg;
    TiXmlDeclaration* decl = new TiXmlDeclaration( "1.0", "", "" );  
    doc.LinkEndChild( decl );  

    TiXmlElement * root = new TiXmlElement( "MyApp" );  
    doc.LinkEndChild( root );  

    TiXmlComment * comment = new TiXmlComment();
    comment->SetValue(" Settings for MyApp " );  
    root->LinkEndChild( comment );  

    TiXmlElement * msgs = new TiXmlElement( "Messages" );  
    root->LinkEndChild( msgs );  

    msg = new TiXmlElement( "Welcome" );  
    msg->LinkEndChild( new TiXmlText( "Welcome to MyApp" ));  
    msgs->LinkEndChild( msg );  

    msg = new TiXmlElement( "Farewell" );  
    msg->LinkEndChild( new TiXmlText( "Thank you for using MyApp" ));  
    msgs->LinkEndChild( msg );  

    TiXmlElement * windows = new TiXmlElement( "Windows" );  
    root->LinkEndChild( windows );  

    TiXmlElement * window;
    window = new TiXmlElement( "Window" );  
    windows->LinkEndChild( window );  
    window->SetAttribute("name", "MainFrame");
    window->SetAttribute("x", 5);
    window->SetAttribute("y", 15);
    window->SetAttribute("w", 400);
    window->SetAttribute("h", 250);

    TiXmlElement * cxn = new TiXmlElement( "Connection" );  
    root->LinkEndChild( cxn );  
    cxn->SetAttribute("ip", "192.168.0.1");
    cxn->SetDoubleAttribute("timeout", 123.456); // floating point attrib

    doc.SaveFile( "appsettings.xml" );  
} 


int main()
{
    write_app_settings_doc( );
  return 0;
}
```

just an example file.
So ..when i compile this with :

> g++ example2.cpp

i get following error message:

```
/tmp/cc6npUsW.o: In function `write_app_settings_doc()':
example2.cpp:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `TiXmlDocument::TiXmlDocument()'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `TiXmlDeclaration::TiXmlDeclaration(char const*, char const*, char const*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `TiXmlNode::LinkEndChild(TiXmlNode*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x8f): undefined reference to `TiXmlElement::TiXmlElement(char const*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `TiXmlNode::LinkEndChild(TiXmlNode*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x112): undefined reference to `TiXmlNode::LinkEndChild(TiXmlNode*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x132): undefined reference to `TiXmlElement::TiXmlElement(char const*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x147): undefined reference to `TiXmlNode::LinkEndChild(TiXmlNode*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x17e): undefined reference to `TiXmlElement::TiXmlElement(char const*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x1cb): undefined reference to `TiXmlNode::LinkEndChild(TiXmlNode*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x1f4): undefined reference to `TiXmlNode::LinkEndChild(TiXmlNode*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x214): undefined reference to `TiXmlElement::TiXmlElement(char const*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x261): undefined reference to `TiXmlNode::LinkEndChild(TiXmlNode*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x28a): undefined reference to `TiXmlNode::LinkEndChild(TiXmlNode*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x2aa): undefined reference to `TiXmlElement::TiXmlElement(char const*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x2bf): undefined reference to `TiXmlNode::LinkEndChild(TiXmlNode*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x2f6): undefined reference to `TiXmlElement::TiXmlElement(char const*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x30b): undefined reference to `TiXmlNode::LinkEndChild(TiXmlNode*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x33d): undefined reference to `TiXmlElement::SetAttribute(char const*, char const*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x358): undefined reference to `TiXmlElement::SetAttribute(char const*, int)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x373): undefined reference to `TiXmlElement::SetAttribute(char const*, int)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x38e): undefined reference to `TiXmlElement::SetAttribute(char const*, int)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x3a9): undefined reference to `TiXmlElement::SetAttribute(char const*, int)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x3c9): undefined reference to `TiXmlElement::TiXmlElement(char const*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x3de): undefined reference to `TiXmlNode::LinkEndChild(TiXmlNode*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x40d): undefined reference to `TiXmlElement::SetAttribute(char const*, char const*)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x42a): undefined reference to `TiXmlElement::SetDoubleAttribute(char const*, double)'
example2.cpp:(.text+0x43d): undefined reference to `TiXmlDocument::SaveFile(char const*) const'
/tmp/cc6npUsW.o: In function `TiXmlString::operator=(char const*)':
example2.cpp:(.text._ZN11TiXmlStringaSEPKc[TiXmlString::operator=(char const*)]+0x23): undefined reference to `TiXmlString::assign(char const*, unsigned int)'
/tmp/cc6npUsW.o: In function `TiXmlString::quit()':
example2.cpp:(.text._ZN11TiXmlString4quitEv[TiXmlString::quit()]+0xc): undefined reference to `TiXmlString::nullrep_'
/tmp/cc6npUsW.o: In function `TiXmlComment::TiXmlComment()':
example2.cpp:(.text._ZN12TiXmlCommentC1Ev[TiXmlComment::TiXmlComment()]+0x15): undefined reference to `TiXmlNode::TiXmlNode(TiXmlNode::NodeType)'
example2.cpp:(.text._ZN12TiXmlCommentC1Ev[TiXmlComment::TiXmlComment()]+0x1e): undefined reference to `vtable for TiXmlComment'
/tmp/cc6npUsW.o: In function `TiXmlText::TiXmlText(char const*)':
example2.cpp:(.text._ZN9TiXmlTextC1EPKc[TiXmlText::TiXmlText(char const*)]+0x17): undefined reference to `TiXmlNode::TiXmlNode(TiXmlNode::NodeType)'
example2.cpp:(.text._ZN9TiXmlTextC1EPKc[TiXmlText::TiXmlText(char const*)]+0x20): undefined reference to `vtable for TiXmlText'
example2.cpp:(.text._ZN9TiXmlTextC1EPKc[TiXmlText::TiXmlText(char const*)]+0x4f): undefined reference to `TiXmlNode::~TiXmlNode()'
/tmp/cc6npUsW.o: In function `TiXmlDocument::~TiXmlDocument()':
example2.cpp:(.text._ZN13TiXmlDocumentD1Ev[TiXmlDocument::~TiXmlDocument()]+0xb): undefined reference to `vtable for TiXmlDocument'
example2.cpp:(.text._ZN13TiXmlDocumentD1Ev[TiXmlDocument::~TiXmlDocument()]+0x24): undefined reference to `TiXmlNode::~TiXmlNode()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am mostly a java developer and i have a lot of problems in c++ to use external libraries.
I dont know when to link . when to include. when i have to make -I/myincludepath/

these files are in the same folder :

> example.cpp tinyxml.h tinyxml.cpp
>   tinystr.h tinystr.cpp

Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like:

```
g++ example2.cpp tinyxml.cpp tinystr.cpp
```

Comment: this worked ... i also forgot : tinyxmlerror.cpp tinyxmlparser.cpp
so the solution was : g++ example2.cpp tinyxml.cpp tinystr.cpp tinyxmlerror.cpp tinyxmlparser.cpp

Comment: Yes -- at some point, you (probably) want t compile all the "tiny" files and then use `ar` to put them together into a library named something like "libtinyxml.a". Then you'd just pass `-ltinxml` on the command line. That has two advantages: it avoids re-compiling the tinyXML code very time you use it, and it it lets the linker add only the necessary code to your executable, instead of adding all of it whether it's needed or not (though it probably then strips out the unnecessary parts, so the difference is minimal).

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, none of these is a library:

```
example.cpp tinyxml.h tinyxml.cpp tinystr.h tinystr.cpp
```

You need to locate the tinyxml library. This location should be described in the  package's documentation, but lets say it's in /foo (it won't be) and is called libtinyxml.a (it probably wont be). You could link it like this:

```
g++ example2.cpp -L/foo -ltinyxml
```

which adds /foo to the link path and looks for libtinyxml.a on it. Or you can simply provide the complete path to the library:

```
g++ example2.cpp /foo/libtinyxml.a
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to learn about Make?
It is actually very simple. Each line beginning at column 0 is an objective with its prerequisites. A line beginning with a tab is describes one step to build the objective. For example:

```
example2: example2.cpp example2.h
    g++ example2.cpp tinyxml.cpp tinystr.cpp -oexample2
```

Or, if you have the library:

```
example2: example2.cpp example2.h
    g++ example2.cpp -Ltinyxml -oexample2
```

Actually, you don't have to specify the compiler you're using. Maybe you're using one here, and another different one in another platform. So you can use the appropriate make's variable:

```
example2: example2.cpp example2.h
    $(CXX) example2.cpp -Ltinyxml -oexample2
```

That's it. Save this as a file with name "Makefile" and, in order to compile your project, just type:

```
$ make
```

And it will compile it if needed.
Further reading:

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You should compile g++ `main.cpp` `tinyxml.cpp` `tinystr.cpp` `tinyxmlparser.cpp` `tinyxmlerror.cpp`

and these files(`main.cpp` `tinyxml.cpp` `tinystr.cpp` `tinyxmlparser.cpp` `tinyxmlerror.cpp` AND `tinyxml.h` `tinystr.h`) must be under one directory while you are compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had this problem yesterday.You can try :g++ *.cpp